# Flexbox compatibility with horizontal pre / code scrolling

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have some code inside `pre` and `code` tags in a bootstrap container that I'd like to scroll horizontally. This normally works fine, until I add a flexbox to my page's `body` in order to accomplish a sticky footer. After this, the `code` no longer scrolls horizontally when the page is narrow (such as for mobile viewing).

Here's my code (note that horizontal scrollbars for the `code` go away as you narrow the window):

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    min-height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
code {
    max-height: 200px;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    word-break: normal !important;
    word-wrap: normal !important;
    white-space: pre !important;
}
.flexer {
    flex: 1;
}
footer {
    background-color: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 docs">
            <p>Some sample code</p>
            <pre><code>Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfilebase: mirrors.arpnetworks.com * centosplus: mirrors.arpnetworks.com* extras:mirrors.arpnetworks.com*rpmforge: mirror.hmc.eduupdates: mirrors.arpnetworks.comExcluding Packages in global exclude list</code></pre>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="flexer"></div>
<footer>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
            footer
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nturor46/1/

Any idea how to use flexbox for sticky footers while still maintaining scrolling `pre` / `code`?

Comment: In the future, please include your code in the question itself. Including a link to JSFiddle without doing so is against the rules.

Comment: @TylerH, it's possible OP didn't include snippet for the same reason I removed it from my answer: It doesn't work. Although code works in fiddle demo, it breaks in SO snippet and doesn't reproduce the problem (or the solution I propose).

Comment: @Michael_B The code works the same in the Stack Snippet for me as it does in JSFiddle, and reproduces the problem. What browser are you using? Either way, the code still needs to be in the question; having it in a Stack Snippet is just extra.

Comment: @TylerH, Chrome 47, 48 and FF. Fiddle rendering scrollbar on content box. SO snippet rendering one long line; no scroll. Definitely a difference here. I had to remove SO snippet from my answer as a result.

Comment: @Michael_B The JSFiddle and the Stack Snippet work identically for me in Firefox `44.0.1` and Chrome `48.0.2564.103 m` and Chrome Version `48.0.2564.109 m`. As you narrow the window, the code window loses its scrollbar and overflows the viewport, giving the browser window a horizontal scrollbar. This is the exact behavior Josh describes. I'm not sure what to tell you.

Comment: @TylerH, not sure the cause. Regardless, you're right about the code. Needs to be included in the question. The demos are optional.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

a simple

```
.container { width:100%; }
```

resizes the website correctly. BUT then, Chrome doesn't let you actually use the scrollbar. This is caused by it overflowing the dimension of all of its containers (apart from BODY).
Hence we gotta tell the browser to correctly recognize the pre node:

```
.container {
  max-width: 100%;
}
pre {
  position: relative;
}
```

This tells Chrome to correctly handle mouse events again AND fixes the layout

Please note that the margin-bottom of the `pre`-node is lost in overflow-country, which could cause your layout to look weird. `max-width` was used in the final version to make sure it doesn't overwrite fixed width statements made in bootstrap

PS: tested in current Chrome and Firefox http://jsfiddle.net/nturor46/32/

Comment: I tried your `.container { width: 100%; }` in Chrome & FF and it works fine. Scrollbar is accessible. I don't see the need for `max-width` and `position: relative`. Looks like the first two lines of your answer are all that is needed.

Comment: @Michael_B You won't see the problem if you just edit his fiddle and rerun it. Chrome apparently caches the working version. If you update the fiddle, do a hard refresh, and then try to use the scrollbar, you'll  see why he added the `position: relative`. Or you can just look at [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/nturor46/38/).

Answer (score 2):

What happens here is **most definitely** a bug in Chrome.

After playing around with your Fiddle, and looking at it with other browsers, I can conclude that this is a Chrome-specific problem. And a curious one.

For some reason, `<div class="col-md-12 docs">` grows to the size it should have (the height of `p` and `pre` together), but doesn't account for the horizontal scrollbar inside the `pre` tag.

Here's an image to demonstrate the problem. The part with the red background is the container.

[image: Chrome bug]

Since `pre` has a border of 1px wide at the bottom, the result leaves a 1px gap for you to actually use the scrollbar. You can try it yourself. Just try to grab the most upper 1px line of the scrollbar.

Removing the flex properties does fix your problem, but we're not going to accept that.

Now, I would've thought that adding a padding of 0.1px to the bottom of the parent would fix the problem, but it didn't. I then tried wrapping the `pre` tag in a `div` with class `chromefix`, and then added the following CSS

```
.chromefix{
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

But that created an even weirder situation where the container grew with the scrollbar for **about 50%**

[image]

So I tried combining the two, but not a lot of difference there.

This is where I started looking at the `pre` tag and its properties. It has `overflow: auto` by Bootstrap default. So what I tried was adding

```
pre{
  overflow-x: scroll !important;
}
```

And guess what? It worked!

So all you have to do is add `overflow-x: scroll !imporant` to `pre`, and you're good to go! Here's a [working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nturor46/16/).

Hope this helps

As a sidenote. I think you want to move `max-height: 200px` to `pre` as well. It won't work when you've applied it to `code`.

Comment: Should work if you add `width: 100%` to `.container`. Might also want to add `display: flex` to `.row` since the O.P. said in [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35196624/2759272) that he plans to add a sidebar.

Comment: @JörnBerkefeld What browser are you using? It's working for me

Comment: @GustvandeWal try narrowing the width of the output frame in your fiddle and you'll see the problem

Comment: @DoctorDestructo That is Bootstrap's media-query... That has nothing to do with my solution to the actual problem

Comment: @GustvandeWal From the OP: "note that horizontal scrollbars for the code go away as you narrow the window". Well, ok, you got me. Your solution does indeed make the scrollbar not go away. Should teach him to make his questions more specific, if nothing else.

Comment: gotta love the Doctor's sarcasm... :D (sorry Gust)

Answer (score 2):

Those bootstrap styles just wreak havoc on natural CSS!

The problem seems to come from a conflict between your `column`-direction flex container and bootstrap rules. It's basically resulting in the horizontal scrollbar shifting from the `pre` / `code` content box to the browser window, when the content box overflows the screen.

With these adjustments, your desired layout seems to work:

- make the primary `.container` div the primary flex container (in your code this role is played by the `body` element)
- move the `footer` element into this new container
- use [flex `auto` margins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276) to stick the footer to the bottom
- override bootstrap `margin`, `padding` and `width` wherever necessary

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 docs">
            <p>Some sample code</p>
            <pre><code>Loading mirror speeds from ... cached hostfilebase</code></pre>
        </div>
    </div>

    <footer>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
                    footer
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body { height: 100%; }

body > .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;                      /* override bootstrap styles */
    padding: 0;                       /* override bootstrap styles */
}

body > .container > .row {
    margin: 0;                        /* override bootstrap styles */
    display: flex;                    /* nested flex container */
    justify-content: center;          /* center content box on page */
}

body > .container > .row > .docs {
    width: 75%;                      /* adjust width of the content box here */
}

code {
    max-height: 200px;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    word-break: normal !important;
    word-wrap: normal !important;
    white-space: pre !important;
}

footer {
    margin-top: auto;                /* stick footer to bottom of container */
    background-color: #CCC;
}
```

[**Revised Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nturor46/15/)

Tested in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: this overwrites the (bootstrap) design

Comment: @JörnBerkefeld, my friend, your answer overrides bootstrap, as well. Shouldn't a div be `width: 100%` by default? (Not that yours isn't a good answer.)

Comment: it actually does not overwrite bootstrap rules because neither max-width nor position is defined for these layers (second & final approach in my answer). I think we agree that this seems to be a weird browser behavior. My approach reminds the browser of what "should be default" ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Problem seems to be with the width of `<pre>`.

When width of your screen goes below `768px` no specific width is applied to the `.container` by bootstrap hence the issue is occurring.

When width of your screen is above `768px` following classes from `bootstrap.css` come in picture.

```
@media (min-width: 1200px)
.container {
    width: 1170px;
}
@media (min-width: 992px)
.container {
    width: 970px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px)
.container {
    width: 750px;
}
```

As you can see once the width goes below `768px` there is no specific width given.

To counter this issue, you have to write your css, something like this.

```
@media (min-width: 480px) {
 .container {
        width: calc(100% - 40px);
    }
}
```

Basically, you have to specify width for `.container` when screen width goes below `768px`. Once you do, it will fix your issue.

Comment: I like this answer because it just extends the current behavior instead of trying to change it. Still fails with really narrow widths, though, but I'm sure you could fix that by adding a few more min-widths. It also suffers from the Chrome bug mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35397304/2759272) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35305829/2759272) (also fixable).

Comment: @DoctorDestructo One can fix issue of really narrow widths simply by editing the media query. I didn't handle the possibility below 480px because really, where would you face such situation?

Comment: I can certainly narrow my browser window to less than 480px.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the prev tag and its content with div like below.

```
<div class="code">{your code goes here}</div>
```

css :

```
.code{
     width:92vw; /*you can change this in media query to specific device width for better results*/
     overflow-x:auto;
}
```

[Working jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/nturor46/7/)

Comment: Using `width:92vw` doesn't quite work because the size of the `code` box doesn't match up with the rest of my content as the page is scaled.

Comment: Here's a fiddle with a sidebar. I'm not sure how to get the `code` box sized just right so that it doesn't bleed over to the sidebar as the page is resized. http://jsfiddle.net/jhalterman/nturor46/9/